# How to count occurence of string in groovy

Tags: groovy

input:

[
{
"Org" : "Test",
"result": "Talent Partner,  Partner, Partner"
}
]

Expected output:

[
{
"Org" : "Test",
"TP": "1",
"Partner" : "2"
}
]

Below is the script, However I am not getting the expected output:

```
def slurper = new JsonSlurper();
def jsonDoc = slurper.parseText(doc);
def NoOfTP = 0;
def Partner = 0;
def NumberOfElements = jsonDoc.result.split(',');
for (int p = 0; p < NumberOfElements; p++) {
    if (NumberOfElements[p] == 'Talent Partner') {
        NoOfTP = NoOfTP + 1;
    } else if (NumberOfElements[p] == 'Partner') {
        Partner = Partner + 1;
    }
}
props.setProperty("document.dynamic.userdefined.NoOfTP", NoOfTP);
props.setProperty("document.dynamic.userdefined.NoOfTP", Partner);

is = new ByteArrayInputStream(JsonOutput.toJson(jsonDoc).getBytes());
dataContext.storeStream(is, props);
}
```

Comment: It should read `p < NumberOfElements.size()` in the for loop expression. Also check the key on the second props statement line. I doubt that both keys should be equal.

Comment: @AndreasDolk Thanks,  I made the changes , it gives error : NO signature of method
def slurper = new JsonSlurper();
def jsonDoc = slurper.parseText(doc);
def NoOfTP = 0;
def Partner = 0;
def NumberOfElements = jsonDoc.result.split(",") ;
for (int p = 0; p < NumberOfElements.size(); p++) {
if (NumberOfElements[p] == "Talent Partner") {
NoOfTP = NoOfTP + 1;
} else if (NumberOfElements[p] == "Partner") {
Partner = Partner + 1;
}}
props.setProperty("document.dynamic.userdefined.NoOfTP", NoOfTP);
props.setProperty("document.dynamic.userdefined.Partner", Partner);